# Does ASP(VBScript) have a function similar to PHP's ini_get?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am converting a File Upload PHP script to ASP.

The PHP script gets the post_max_size variable from php.ini with ini_get().

```
$POST_MAX_SIZE = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

First, is there a similar file or methodology employed by IIS or .NET. If there is, is there a similar variable that controls the max post size. And assuming both of those are true, is there something similar in ASP(VBScript) that can pull the variable from IIS or .NET?

I am not an ASP developer, so I am at a complete loss. Any help would be appreciated, even helping me ask the correct question if that is the appropriate path to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But there are many providers for achieve to configuration.
PHP's `post_max_size` equal to `ASPmaxRequestEntityAllowed` for ASP in the IIS config.
Following sample uses ADSI or WMI provider.
Works if you have permission and provider(s) installed.

```
Dim INSTANCE_ID : INSTANCE_ID = Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_ID")

'ADSI provider
Response.Write GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/"& INSTANCE_ID &"/Root").ASPmaxRequestEntityAllowed

Response.Write "<hr />"

'WMI provider
Response.Write GetObject("winmgmts:/root/MicrosoftIISv2")._
Get("IIsWebVirtualDirSetting='W3SVC/"& INSTANCE_ID &"/ROOT'").ASPmaxRequestEntityAllowed
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking with our IT guy to see if we have ADSI or WMI installed.  If nothing else, I'll just figure out what our Post Max Size is and define it manually. It's not the perfect solution, but it will work!