# ASP upload files to server and limit size

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, filesize

I am looking for a free ASP script that will allow me to upload files to my server but limiting the size and type of the files uploaded. It should also inform the user of the errors and not throwing him to IIS error page because of IIS size limits.

I'd really appriciate if there will be an addition that will check the size limit before the file is actually uploaded (meaning - at the browser)

Is there anything like this?

Thanks
Tal

Comment: Have you googled this? there are many examples

Comment: ofcourse, couldnt find any that will do all that

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx does everything bar the check before

Comment: thats cute, but I am looking for classic asp not .net

Comment: Have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436899/does-aspvbscript-have-a-function-similar-to-phps-ini-get/7439122 may be helpful

Answer (score -1):

I found this code by a guy named Lewis Moten several years ago:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4

It includes checking of file size, though it does happen server-side, not client-side.
I used this code for a project a few years ago and it worked great.